# iOS Settings Bundle Editable

Tags: xcode, settings.bundle

Is there a way to allow the user to add additional items to one group in the settings bundle? Specifically, I a would like the user to be able to specify a list of URLs and Site Names within Settings. The functionality is almost exactly the same as the Twitter app that allows for a list of usernames and passwords and in the mail app where the server name, inbound and outbound email server names/addresses are maintained. I am familiar with doing this with archive, CoreData and SQLite within the app, but would prefer to keep key settings outside the app as I would like to intentionally distance the config data from the user interface.
Thanks
Derrick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you're pretty limited with what you can do in the settings. There isn't any way to run code, so there can be no add buttons or changes to the model - its basically predefined key value pairs. Twitter and mail are first-party apps so they can do things in settings the rest of us can't.

Comment: Thanks. That is what I was afraid of. So much for elegance. Will structure same way I have in the past (in app using archive or CoreData).

Comment: You can use the default grouped table styles, and transitions (flip etc) to make it clear you are going "under the hood". if your app has its own visual style the difference will be clear. I agree with you though.

Comment: You can still store it in user defaults, though - you can put an array of strings or dictionaries in there. No need for core data unless you're already using it.